WQL StdRegProv for registry keys
I searched the whole Internet, but I still haven't found an easy way to run a WQL query to get values from the registry, for example through StdRegProv. In the Microsoft documentation, all the examples use the primitive query "select * from win32_service". But the query "select * from StdRegProv" returns nothing (empty). The StdRegProv class has a GetStringValue() method that should be used to get values from the registry, but how do I write this in WQL???
it is easy to get the value via VB or via powershell : Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem" - Computer name IEWIN7 -Credentials IEWIN7\Admin
